# How can i use Like in cake php

Tags: cakephp-2.1

> **i want the alternative cakephp code for the above query**

Select * from book where title like '%java%;

Comment: $b = $this->Book->find('all',array ('condition'=> array ('Book.title LIKE' =>$a))); am using this one but it does not giving the search answer

Comment: make sure $a includes the % symbols. if you echo it it should be %java%. Otherwise youll need to put them in the array manually

Comment: $c = '%'.$a.'%'; now it will working while print_r($c); output %java%

Comment: It should work with $c instead of $a then in the find query

Comment: $b = $this->Book->find('all',array ('condition'=> array ('Book.title LIKE' =>$c))); now am getting all fields in view instead of java am getting c c# cobol every thing

Comment: change condition to conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, assuming you are using a find() query.

You can specify the conditions array as follows:

```
"conditions" => array("Book.title like" => "%java%")
```

or

```
"conditions" => array("Book.title like '%java%'")
```

I think both will work

Comment: technically it should be Book.title, but it will probably work either way as you only have one model.

Answer (score 1):

[Docu complex find conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html)

```
$this->Post->find('first', array (
    "Author.name" => "Bob", 
    "OR" => array (
        "Post.title LIKE" => "%magic%",
        "Post.created >" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks"))
    )
));
```